# How can I set Sunspot to search for sequences of characters instead of words?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sunspot, sunspot-rails

I wanted to understand whether Sunspot, in standard mode, searches for words or sequences of characters in full-text search and how to make it search for sequences.

For example, I have the following setup:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   searchable do
      text :email
   end
end
```

with one `User` with e-mail "panayotis@matsinopoulos.gr"

the following query :

```
search = User.search do 
   fulltext 'matsinopoulos'
end
```

does not bring any result, whereas:

```
search = User.search do
   fulltext 'panayotis@matsinopoulos.gr'
end
```

brings.

Is there any configuration setting for sunspot to match sequences of characters instead of words?

Or, am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One needs to configure file:

```
solr/conf/schema.xml
```

The standard entry:

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="false">
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

has to be turned to:

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="false">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.NGramFilterFactory"
            minGramSize="3"
            maxGramSize="30"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>`
</fieldType>
```

A very nice reference on Solr configuration can be found here:

http://techbot.me/2011/01/full-text-search-in-in-rails-with-sunspot-and-solr/

but, watch out that when it comes to partial words matching this reference talks about the `EdgeNGramFilterFactory` which indexes the beginnings of the words only. For making Solr match any part of the word, the `NGramFilterFactory` needs to be used.

Note also that we have set `minGramSize` to `3` and `maxGramSize` to `30`. So, patterns with length less than 3 or greater than 30 will not be returned in queries.